# Region and language selection in URL

Tags: views, 7

Is it possible in Drupal?

I'm developing a website in multilingual. It contains region (country name E.g USA, German, french....) and language (English, French, Japan....) selection.

When user select the region it brings in URL.

Eg: http://www.example.com/us[region-name]/en[language-name]

For single region, we can select many language

Eg: http://www.example.com/us[region-name]/jp[language-name] or http://www.example.com/us[region-name]/fr[language-name]

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by using [Purl](https://www.drupal.org/project/purl) with help of mytheme_url_outbound_alter()